# make Keras 'None' batch size unchanged, using tf.scatter_nd

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I need to input a pooling module to the LSTM decoder, and I'm constructing this using a custom layer with the encoder LSTM states and Keras Input layer as inputs. In this custom layer, I need to scatter the updates to the indices:

```
updates: <tf.Tensor --- shape=(None, 225, 5, 32) dtype=float32>
indices: <tf.Tensor --- shape=(None, 225) dtype=int32>
```

with `tf.scatter_nd` to create a tensor with shape=(None, 960, 5, 32) , something like this:

```
tf.scatter_nd(tf.expand_dims(indices, 2), updates, shape=[None, 960, 5, 32])
```

but the problem is that doing this, rises error due to NoneType in shape and I don't want to declare the `batch_size` in it because it is a Keras layer and only is certain in the learning process. in this state the working version of code is this:

```
tf.scatter_nd(tf.expand_dims(indices, 2), updates, shape=[960, 5, 32])
        >>> <tf.Tensor 'ScatterNd_4:0' shape=(960, 5, 32) dtype=float32>
```

that has ignored the batch_size in the output.
Is there any alternative way to construct the needed output tensor instead of `tf.scatter_nd` or a way to make this work properly?

Comment: I am having a similar issue, if you found out a solution please share.. Thank you

Comment: Have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with `tf.scatter_nd` operation. I solved it by infering batch size during runtime using `tf.shape(input)[0]`. So in your case, the following code should work:

```
bs = tf.shape(indices)[0]
tf.scatter_nd(tf.expand_dims(indices, 2), updates, shape=[bs, 960, 5, 32])
```